# Python List Iteration Using Dynamic Length

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm wanting to iterate over a loop in python but am not sure how to go about it.

```
channels = [1, 2]
for channel in channels:
    channel_filters = filters.channel(channel)
```

I need to end up like this:

```
channel_filters = filters.channel(1) | filters.channel(2) | filters.channel(3)
```

But need it to be dynamic with the length of the list.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction on how best to achieve this?

Comment: is filter going to be a bitmask, and those "|" are intended to be bitwise ors?

Comment: The "|" is meant to be similar to an OR operator so I suppose it is bitwise

Comment: you can use the `|=` operator

Comment: Thank you, but my actual issue is taking each value out of the channels = [1, 2] list and then flattening it into one variable: filters = filters.channel(1) | filters.channel(2) | filters.channel(3)

Comment: yes, you can do that with `filters = 0; for channel in channels: filters |= filters.channel(channel)`

Comment: I may have obscured the question with using 'filters =' because when I run your suggestion with that, I get "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>        
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'int' and 'NoneType'".

Comment: yes, you can only do bitwise operations on ints.  If filters.channel() can return None, then you will need to fix that  to zero or add a result test.

Comment: Thank you toppk! Got this working in the end. My issue was that the channel numbers were negative and so were not integers resulting in failed tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue with the answer shared by toppk.

```
channel_filters = 0;
channels = [-1, -2]
for channel in channels:
    temp_channel=abs(channel)
    channel_filters |= -abs(temp_channel)
    print(channel_filters)
```